# Renomear pastas alterando os caracteres minúsculo para maiúsculo e obter o número total de pastas alteradas

Tags: python

Estou criando um script em python para renomear nomes de pastas que estão em minúsculo para maiúsculo. No exemplo de código abaixo já consigo essa tarefa.

```
import os
basedir = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Teste'

for name_folder in os.listdir(basedir):
    os.rename(os.path.join(basedir, name_folder), 
              os.path.join(basedir, name_folder.upper()))
```

Gostaria de obter mais informação sobre os arquivos do diretório base (***basedir***)

**Perguntas:**

**1.** Número total de arquivos.

**2.** Número total de pastas.

**3.** Número total de pasta em que houve transformação.

Comment: Acho que você esqueceu de renomear o `basedir` para `diretorio_base` ali na segunda linha.

Comment: Obrigado pela observação. Já editei a pergunta.

Comment: @Rfroes87, sua resposta era exatamente o que eu queria. Valeu.

Comment: @Rfroes87, estou alterando um pouco o código, existe uma maneira fácil de implementar uma verifcação se o caminho é realmente um diretório?
`dir = str(input('Digite um caminho: '))`

Comment: Você pode usar a função `os.path.isdir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que a função `walk` seria mais apropriada para seu caso de uso. Você poderia usá-la desta forma:

```
import os

# Inicializando estatísticas
num_files, num_dir, num_transform = [0] * 3

"""
Aqui cada diretório e subdiretório vai ser uma tupla com 3 elementos contendo
respectivamente o nome do diretório e o total de subdiretórios e arquivos contidos
no mesmo
"""
for dir, subdirs, files in os.walk('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Teste'):
   # Iterando subdiretórios
   for subdir in subdirs:

      # Caso o subdiretório não esteja em caixa alta
      if not subdir.isupper():

         # Renomear diretório da mesma forma e incrementar contador de 'transformação'
         os.rename(os.path.join(dir, subdir), os.path.join(dir, subdir.upper()))
         num_transform += 1

      # Incrementar total de diretórios lidos
      num_dir += 1

   # Contar número de arquivos no diretório correntes adicionando ao contador apropriado
   num_files += len(files)
```

### Exemplo de saída

```
>>> print(f'num_dir: {num_dir} / num_files: {num_files} / num_transform: {num_transform}')
num_dir: 3 / num_files: 2 / num_transform: 2
```